# How to set current_user in flask shell on start

Tags: flask, flask-login

My code depends on there being an active user which I get from `current_user` thread local.

When running `flask shell` user is obviously not set. So how do I set `current_user` automatically each time `flask shell` is started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work inside request context to be able to login user.

Working example:

```
In [1]: from app.users.models import User

In [2]: user = User.query.first()

In [3]: request_ctx = app.test_request_context()  # you need to work inside request context to login user

In [4]: request_ctx.push()

In [5]: from flask_login import login_user

In [6]: login_user(user)

Out[6]: True

In [7]: from flask_security import current_user

In [8]: current_user.id == user.id

Out[8]: True
```

Comment: Is there a flask shell hook that can execute this code when I start it?

Comment: Have a look at `shell_context_processor` https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.shell_context_processor You can implement a function logging your user and returning it it the context available in shell.